# как увеличить шрифт в терминале phpStrorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Как увеличить шрифт терминала phpStrom? Не как найти не могу, если это можно сделать конечно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настройки находятся тут:

```
Settings → Editor → Colors & Fonts → Console Font
```

После этого надо перезагрузить IDE

---

Еще в настройки можно попасть нажав <kbd>CTRL/CMD+Shift+A</kbd> и вбить `console font`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А дальше по схеме выше.